# Rqt command line interface - killing plugins and switching perspectives

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! :)

I am struggling with the (probably considered) advanced features of `rqt` namely using the command line interface in order to control a running `rqt` instance using IPC (inter-process communication). This question consists of two parts:

- **Killing plugins** started as separate processes
- **Switching perspectives**

**System:** Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo (I think it was updated 2-3 months ago)

---

**Killing plugins started as serparate processes**

The question here is to **find a workaround of the problem described in this section of the post**.

Looking at the `--help` of `rqt` I got the following (do feel free to correct me if I'm wrong):

- `-m` (long: `--multi-process`)  - starts each `rqt` plugin as a separate process which means that I can get the PID of every pluging in order to manipulate it somehow using UNIX signals. *Tested and working as described.*
- `--command-pid RQT_PID` - used in a combination with other `--command-*` terminal parameters to control the running `rqt` instance (oldest one by default which is not something that I need to consider since my use case involves running just a single instance of `rqt`).  *Tested and working as described.*

  - `--command-pid RQT_PID --command-start-plugin RQT_PLUGIN_NAME` - given the PID of the running `rqt` I can pass the name of a `rqt` plugin I want to start.  *Tested and working as described.*

    **Example:** `rqt --command-pid 10816 --command-start-plugin rqt_rviz/RViz` adds `rviz` the my  running `rqt`

So far so good. The problem is when I want to stop a plugin everything turns into...well...you know what. I was unable to find a `rqt`-friendly way of doing that (there is for example no such command as `--command-stop-plugin RQT_PLUGIN_NAME`) hence the only way that I have found so far is to send a `SIGTERM` to the PID of the respective plugin.

I have tried using `SIGINT` but it doesn't seem to work at all and also even when I use `SIGTERM` the plugin still seems to be running (second image). I wrote **seems** since the processes is actually no longer there however the plugin (without its content!) remains and also under `Running` in the menu I can still see `Close RQT_PLUGIN_NAME` (see third image). Clicking on it doesn't do anything and the entry in the menu doesn't disappear. To be honest I find it very unlikely that anything but `kill` is to be used to close externally such plugins because of the absence of a `--command-stop-plugin ...` and the fact that the `--command-start-plugin ...` takes just the `rqt` plugin's name which begs the question "What will happen if I want to start and then stop N instances of the same plugin next to each other?"

**Before SIGTERM to RViz plugin**
[image: image description]

**After SIGTERM to RViz plugin** (the plugin is still partially there)
[image: image description]

**After SIGTERM to RViz plugin** (the plugin is still registered as a running plugin)
[image: image description]

Things get even weirder when I reopen `rqt` (without `--clean-config` enable of course) - the "corrupted" plugin is loaded and (of course) it appears as one would expect from a pluging that wasn't closed during the previous `rqt` session.

I might be doing something wrong but this seems like a bug to me. So far I have tested it with 3 plugins - `rviz`, `shell` and `rqt_graph`. Depending on the plugin the aftermath of a `SIGTERM` is different though the `behaviour I've described above is always present:

- `rqt_graph` (full name used when calling command: `rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph` ) - I get random strange positioning of the contents of that plugin especially when I have no other plugins currently shown in the perspective - sometimes it takes up the whole perspective (expected behaviour) but sometimes it takes just 1/4 or so of it (placed horizontally) leaving the rest completely blank.
- `rviz` (full name used when calling command: `rqt_rviz/RViz`) - no additional strange things happening beside the "default" abnormal behaviour
- `shell` (full name used when calling command: `rqt_shell.shell.Shell`) - the `xterm` gets detached (hence it keeps on living). Here this is obviously due to the fact that the `rqt_shell` is actually just a view of an externally running `xterm`.

In addition to all that whenever a plugin is started as a separate process there is actually no way of retrieving the PID of that plugin so one has to monitor the currently running tasks on the system and detect if a new entry has appeared and after that parse the command that represents the process (the example above shows me `/usr/bin/python -u /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rqt --qt-binding=pyqt --embed-plugin=rqt_rviz/RViz ...`) in order to detect if that new process is actually the one that represents the plugin (lucky enough one can use `--list-plugins` to get all the available plugins). This is a more of a missing feature but still...

---

**Switching perspectives**

This is more of a lack of knowledge and need for an explanation how to handle perspectives properly but also yet another weird behaviour using the `rqt` terminal interface.

Using `rqt --command-pid RQT_PID --command-switch-perspective RQT_PERSPECTIVE_NAME` it is possible to change the perspective of a `rqt` instance. To my knowledge a perspective is just a "snapshot" of the currently opened `rqt` plugins along with their own settings (I had to dig quite deep to see where the whole `save_settings(...)` and `load_settings(...)` due to the project I'm currently working on and I'm still not sure what is going on behind the scenes). So when a perspective is loaded I expect to see the plugins that it contains with previously defined layout. To my surprise I got quite the strange results **especially** after switching between two perspectives multiple time using the command above:

**First opening of a perspective containing three plugins**
[image: image description]

**Switching multiple time between perspectives**
**Note:** Every time a switched to a perspective I waited for it to actually appear in `rqt`
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

The perspectives I have are as follows:

- `Default` perspective is the default for `rqt` which in my case is an empty one
- `diagnostics` contains the `Robot Monitor`
- `messages` contains three plugins - `Topic Monitor` (on the left, vertical from top to bottom), `Message Publisher` (on the right, top half) and `Message Type Browser` (on the right, bottom half)

In another terminal session (where `rqt` is running) I got the following errors whenever one of the perspectives was loaded:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/3025e63e8824e03b5ef3c7cfa0c569ec

I might be wrong here but this doesn't seem like a normal behaviour to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231349/rqt-command-line-interface---killing-plugins-and-switching-perspectives/) by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not surprised that simply killing the processes doesn't work well. `rqt` doesn't know that the subprocess has been killed. The solution here would be to implement a `--command-stop-plugin` option. Since you can already perform this task through the UI it shouldn't be too difficult to expose it as in the CLI.

The problem you have with switching the perspective from the command line sounds like this ticket: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/108

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0